# Is putting images of God in marriage invitation acceptable?

Tags: gods, sin

We put images of God in every marriage invitation or in newspapers etc.,.

People neglect those papers or invitations.Sometimes we can see those kind of invitation or newspapers in **streets**. We respect same god who is present in temple. But neglect who is on papers!

So who gets the sin? The people who print god images acquire sin or who throw those papers or invitation cards get sin?

Comment: great question. it is wrong to disrespect images of God. It is not wrong per-se to distribute his images. But practically speaking, you can keep it to a minimum if you're concerned that people will disrespect it. Print 2 invitations - one only for close family with God's image in your native language, and a general 'modern' english invitation for colleagues & friends without God's image.

Comment: @ram Give scriptural references. Haha. Just kidding. ram's comment is very correct. This question had come to me too. Invitations​ without God photos should be preferred to that with God photo, for the purpose of distribution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the following verse which are  words of Lord Shiva.

> Agnou Tishtathi ViprAnam Hrudi Devo ManishinAm |
>   **PratimAswapravuddhAnAm Sarvatra ViditAtmanAm ||**
>
> ......
>
> For the brahmins God resides in fire, for the manishi (or
>   mahatma) God resides in his heart, **for the unintelligent he resides
>   in idols but for the self-realized he resides everywhere.**
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 9-44.**

So, it actually depends. If someone thinks he has successfully enclosed God in a small piece of paper, he can think of, putting that paper in some dirty places, like the streets, as an insult to him. But in truth none have the power to insult God like that, because he resides everywhere including even on the streets which apparently look dirty.

But, having said that, such behavior is not expected from persons who love God even a bit.

Any things related to him (like his images, nirmalayas etc) are ideally best disposed by immersing them in flowing rivers like the Ganges.